# Write a program with one & only if statement that

Tags: code-challenge

### Challenge: You Are The Teacher

Everyone knows that simple task of receiving a grade, and telling if the student:

> - is approved,
> - will attend the summer school, or
> - failed.

In this challenge, you must write a program that does that, but using the maximum of one `if` statement (also ternary operators count as `if`).

The grade will be an integer from 0 to 10.

```
situation   outputs
-------------------------
grade >= 7: Approved
grade >= 3: Summer School
grade  < 3: Failed
```

You can do **whatever** you want, write in any language.

Fastest working answer wins.

Comment: What about list indexing?

Comment: @Volatility Tricky and worky, but ew... let's think of something better =P ("Unfortunately" would still count as a correct answer)

Comment: This problem is far too trivial to be assessable on speed. To be able to compare performance with any confidence, you need the programs to run for a minute, not for about ten clock cycles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Ruby

```rb
def x(mark)
    possible_results = ['','Failed', 'Failed', 'Summer school', 'Approved']

    index = (mark + 1).to_s(2).length

    possible_results[index]
end
```

This uses the fact that the length of the binary representation of the numbers 0-10 is pretty close to the required classification.

Online test: http://ideone.com/y0kLqY

Answer (score 7):

#### Ruby

Using regular expressions:

```
puts "Failed012Summer School3456Approved78910"[/\D*(?=\d*#{gets.chomp})/]
```

Plain array indexing:

```
puts ["Failed","Summer School","Approved"][(gets.to_i+1)/4]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Python2: 65**

Bonus: it doesn't use *any* conditional expression.

```
g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
```

Example output:

```
>>> g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
10
Approved
>>> g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
7
Approved
>>> g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
6
Summer School
>>> g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
3
Summer School
>>> g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
2
Failed
```

Answer (score 3):

## C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return (a < b) * a + (a >= b) * b;
}

const char *grade_to_string(int grade)
{
    const char * grades[3] = { "Failed", "Summer school", "Approved" };
    return grades[min(((grade + 1) >> 2), 2)];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int grade = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d = %s\n", grade, grade_to_string(grade));
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -O3 grade.c
$ time for i in $(seq -1 20) ; do ./a.out $i ; done
-1 = Failed
0 = Failed
1 = Failed
2 = Failed
3 = Summer school
4 = Summer school
5 = Summer school
6 = Summer school
7 = Approved
8 = Approved
9 = Approved
10 = Approved
11 = Approved
12 = Approved
13 = Approved
14 = Approved
15 = Approved
16 = Approved
17 = Approved
18 = Approved
19 = Approved
20 = Approved

real    0m0.120s
user    0m0.025s
sys     0m0.042s
$
```

Comment: I count one ternary operator and one if.

Comment: Well `main` is just a test harness, so I don't count the `if` in that - I'll remove it though if it makes you happy. ;-)

Comment: The spec asks for a program, so I think you have to count `main`. It would be more interesting, though, to keep that `if` and remove the one in `min` ;)

Comment: Challenge accepted !

Answer (score 2):

### Perl

```
sub f {
  my $grade = shift;
  my $result = 0;
  for (++$grade ; $grade > 1; $grade >>= 1) {
    ++$result;
  }
  return ("Failed", "Failed", "Summer school", "Approved")[$result];
}
```

(The for-loop test constitutes the program's one permitted "if statement".)

Answer (score 1):

## R

```
g=function(x)cut(x,c(0,3,7,10),
                 labels=c("Failed","Summer school","Approved"),
                 right=FALSE, include=TRUE)
```

Usage:

```
> g(2)
[1] Failed
Levels: Failed Summer school Approved
> g(7)
[1] Approved
Levels: Failed Summer school Approved
> g(3)
[1] Summer school
Levels: Failed Summer school Approved
```

Function `cut` in R converts a numeric into a factor (categorical) according to the interval in which it falls. It is vectorized:

```
> g(0:10)
[1] Failed       Failed       Failed       Summer school Summer school Summer school Summer school
[8] Approved      Approved      Approved      Approved     
Levels: Failed Summer school Approved
```

Answer (score 0):

## Awk

```awk
{
  print check($1,0,2,"Failed") check($1,3,6,"Summer School") check($1,7,10,"Approved")
}

function check(grade,lower,upper,result)
{
  if (grade>=lower && grade<=upper) return result
}
```

(There are enough clever solutions, so I felt the need to post a brute force one too.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ for i in {0..10}; do echo -n $i\ ; awk grade.awk <<< $i; done
0 Failed
1 Failed
2 Failed
3 Summer School
4 Summer School
5 Summer School
6 Summer School
7 Approved
8 Approved
9 Approved
10 Approved
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL

```
'Failed' 'Summer School' 'Approved'⌷⍨+/⎕≥0 3 7
```

Explanation:

- `⎕≥0 3 7`: read input, see if it is bigger or equal to 0, 3 and 7 (this gives a vector of bits, i.e. if the input is `5` this gives `1 1 0`)
- `+/`: sum the vector (giving an index into the list)
- `⌷⍨`: select the corresponding string from the list

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, Thanks to @Bakuriu

```
function decision(g) {
    var d = ["Approved","Summer School","Failed"];
    return d[(g<7)+(g<3)]
} 




console.log(decision(2)); ==> Failed
console.log(decision(5)); ==> Summer School
console.log(decision(9)); ==> Approved
console.log(decision(1)); ==> Failed
console.log(decision(4)); ==> Summer School
```

Answer (score -3):

## Java

```
public static String getFeedback(int grad) {
    String str = grad>=7? "Approved" : grad>=3 ?  "Summer School" : grad<3 ? "Failed"  : "";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: 1) That in not a program, just a snippet. At least post the whole method. 2) There are 3 ternary operators while only 1 is allowed.